# Estrutura de Projeto em Django

Tags: python, django

Eu instalei o Django em um projeto e gostaria de deixar a estrutura de pastas um tanto parecida com o Laravel. Eu consigo me organizar melhor assim. 
Mas não sei se é possível usando tal framework.

Gostaria assim:

```
PROJETO
--- venv
--- site
    --- settings.py
    --- urls.py
--- app_1
--- app_2
--- app_3
--- resources
    --- sass
    --- js
--- dist
    --- css
    --- js
    --- img
```

Eu gostaria de usar o gulp para compilar os arquivos de dentro da pasta `resources` para a pasta `dist`.

Essa pasta `dist` gostaria que fosse a minha pasta `static`.
Eu até montei a estrutura, mas não consigo apontá-la no meu `settings.py` para que leia os arquivos dela.

Meu arquivo `settings.py` está assim:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')
```

Não sei se estou fazendo certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalho de forma parecida e utilizo a seguinte estrutura.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Quando eu rodo o comando **python manage.py collectstatic** ele roda uma rotina pré-build pegando vários arquivos estáticos das aplicações instaladas complementares do pip e joga dentro da pasta staticfiles, a partir disso meu builder script na máquina pega e copia todos os arquivos para **static**, então minha pasta final é definida pela variável **STATICFILES_DIRS**.

Veja se te ajudei :)